# Can’t restart after update to Catalina 10.15.4

Tags: macos-catalina

I have a 2017 iMac which was running 10.15.3 without problem. I installed the 10.15.4 update, but on restart, I repeatedly got the message ‘Your computer restarted because of a problem. Press a key or wait for a few seconds to continue startup’. Eventually I then got a ‘No entry’ logo and the machine shuts down.

What I did: Tried starting in safe mode, reset the smc, reset the NVRAM, restarting after each change. This resulted in the same message each time.

Tried restarting in recovery mode and got to the MacOS Utilities screen. From there I tried a reinstall of MacOS, and then a recovery from time machine with the same result both times.

I then successfully booted from a clone of the hard disK I made (before the update) to an external disk with Carbon Copy Cloner. This allowed me to run First Aid (Disk Utility) on the main disk. First Aid reported no errors on the disk.

I then recloned the external disk back to the main disk and tried a restart, getting the same error message as before.

It seems to me that the update did something to the main drive but there are no clues as to what. Can anyone suggest what I can try next? Taking the machine to a dealer is not an option because of the lockdown.

All help gratefully received.
*** Update ***
Tried verbose restart. Didn’t get to the scrolling display of messages but instead got a block of text in the Centre of the screen, at the bottom of which is 
‘This system automatically restarted after panic. 
Fusion tier 2 device is null
Got error 6 reading at pos 0 in obj I’d —-some big no——
File read returned 0x7
Error loading kernel cache 0x7’

**Update 2 ***
Ran first aid from recovery mode -> disk utility on macos base system, Mackintosh HD and Mackintosh HD - Data. All completed without flagging an error.

Comment: How much free space was there on your system disk prior to the update? According to this website (https://iboysoft.com/mac-data-recovery/mac-computer-wont-boot-after-macos-update.html), it can be a factor in the sense that without enough (how much, I don't know) free space, the update does install but macOS won't boot. Have you tried verbose? It's hard to see what's what in that mode, it goes so fast, I know, but an error message could pop up that would give you some indication on where to look.

Comment: SYstem reports 1.9 TB available, so I dont think space is likely to be a factor.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/386578/can-t-restart-after-catalina-update-to-10-15-4

Comment: Sorry about the cross posting, I wasn’t sure which site was the most appropriate so tried both. Didn’t realize it was frowned upon.

Comment: Lotsa things are frowned upon round here... :-D EDIT: so, verbose?

Comment: Have updated problem above with results of verbose restart.

Comment: You've got a kernel panic on restart, due to something going on with your Fusion drive. Fusion is a hybrid storage solution proposed by Apple, with Flash storage for system and programs, and a regular hard drive to store user data. Apparently, the firmware on your Fusion drive has issues. If you have connected an external drive of any kind to your Mac (USB pendrive, Thunderbolt drive, whatever), unplug them and check this in Finder: does your Fusion drive show one or two icons in the This Mac window? If it's only one, you're good; if it's two, you might need to consider other options...

Comment: @Didier 35:   Not sure I completely understood your last comment. This is what I did: Disconnected external drive and rebooted  with same result. Reconnected and rebooted from the external drive. Under the storage tab of ‘About this Mac’ I see one icon for Mackintosh HD. Don’t know how to get the ‘This Mac‘ window? What other options are there to consider?

Comment: Another thought. The system has Sophos Home Antivirus and Epson printing installed. I believe both of these install kernel extensions. It could be that there is an incompatibility problem.  Any thoughts on that? How might I deal with that?

Comment: About this Mac is OK, that's what I meant. Your issues with upgrading macOS seem to stem from a not-so-up-to-date firmware on your Fusion drive combo. You can try the following (entirely harmless): shutdown your Mac entirely, wait about 30 seconds, then press the power button for several seconds (not one push, a constant pressure) until the Power light starts flashing and long tone/beep starts sounding. At this point, you can release pressure on the Power button. A gray screen should show up, and a progress bar will indicate how firmware update is proceeding. When done, your Mac will boot.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Did that with external drive disconnected but same message.

Comment: I saw that using Recovery mode -> Macos Utils-> Terminal, you can use the command diskutil resetfusion. This sounds like it might be useful or it might do untold damage. Can anyone offer advice on doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by sending the iMac off for repair and reloading from time machine. The repairer 'broke' and rebuilt the fusion drive but otherwise couldn't find anything wrong. Now very nervous about trying the upgrade again.